# How to find the optimal solution of a convex program given all KKT points?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Suppose we have a parametric convex program with some constraints.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\max_{x} \: & f(x,\mathbf{a})\\
& g_1(x,\mathbf{a})\le 0 \\
& g_2(x,\mathbf{a}) \le 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{a}$ is a vector of parameters. I can obtain all KKT points and their corresponding Lagrangian multipliers. I am wondering if it is possible to find the optimal solution based on KKT points and multipliers by conditioning on them? I mean, I want to find conditions and then say if condition 1 is true, the optimal solution will be the first KKT point, and so on.

If there is any example, I would be thankful if you can share it.

Comment: If your problem satisfies a constraint qualification (CQ), you know that all solutions are among the KKT points. Hence, you can just take the KKT points with the smallest objective value. If a CQ does not apply, there might be solutions which are not KKT points. In this case, it is not possible to determine the solutions by just looking at the KKT points.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other method except evaluating all KKT points? I mean based on lagrange multipliers, and solutions, is it possible to define some conditions for optimality of each point?

Comment: I have to point out that all the KKT points for convex program must be optimal solution (without any CQ) and this is the so-called KKT sufficient condition.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. All KKT points can be optimal but not simultaneously. For example, suppose we have $\{\max_x \: ax \: | \: -1\le x\le 1\}$. Here, 1 is optimal if $a>0$ and -1 is optimal if $a<1$. I wanna find some conditions like these ones for the optimality of each KKT point.

Comment: Crossposted to OR.SE: [How to find the optimal solution of a convex program given all KKT points?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6741/491)